# Printing current time in C++ updating every frames along with getting input

Tags: c++, time, console

I was making a project for my assignment in C++ and i thought it would look good to print current time in the corner of the screen. I searched for this, I studied the ctime header a little bit and was able to print the current time and update it every 1 second using loop and sleep().

But I also want to get input at the same time. I tried and came up with the following code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <ctime>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    time_t curr ;
    char a;
    tm *currTime;
    while (true) {
         curr = time(NULL);
         currTime = localtime(&curr);
         std::cout<<"Current time: "<<asctime(currTime);
         std::cout<<"Choose a number: ";
         if(kbhit()) {
             a = getch();
             std::cout<<a;
             break;
         }
         Sleep(100);
         system("cls");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But this take input as soon as I press my key. Is there any way to take input by pressing key and then pressing enter key? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to realize is that when you press `enter` so called control characters will be sent by the keyboard. On Windows systems a newline(enter) is represented by two such characters, namely carriage return and line feed. For more information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII

For your purposes it is enough to detect the carriage return and to keep the previous character in a variable to know what character was pressed before the enter.

Here is the code which will do just that. You may want to validate the `prevChar` variable with `isdigit()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    time_t curr;
    char prevChar = '\0';
    char currChar = '\0';
    tm *currTime;

    while (true)
    {
        curr = time(NULL);
        currTime = localtime(&curr);
        std::cout << "Current time: " << asctime(currTime);
        std::cout << "Choose a number: ";
        if (kbhit())
        {
            currChar = getch();
            if (currChar == '\r')
            {
                // carriage return ('\r') is always followed by line feed ('\n') on Windows systems
                // do something with the previous char
                std::cout << "the character you entered before pressing enter: " << prevChar << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            prevChar = currChar;
        }
        Sleep(100);
        system("cls");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother.. It will work.. Thanks for helping